# 2 circles with common chords , their points of tangency intersects a circle circumscribing them ,prove that the line between point of intersect is 2r.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Let Ω be a circle with a chord AB which is not a diameter. Let Γ1 be a circle on one side of AB such that it is tangent to AB at C and internally tangent to Ω at D. Likewise, let Γ2 be a circle on the other side of AB such that it is tangent to AB at and internally tangent to Ω at F. Suppose the line DC intersects Ω at X≠D and the line FE intersects Ω at Y≠F. Prove that XY is a diameter of Ω.
[image]
Could Someone Please tell whether my proof is correct or not ?Thanks in advance !

Comment: Fig. 17 in this document deals partly with the same figure https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.02593.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here is a figure on which you can decently make a reasoning.

It is made with Geogebra (I could have done it with Desmos).

[image]